# Trying to get number of cores remotely

Tags: windows, cmd, wmic, cpu-cores

I am trying to get the number of cores for multiple windows computers/servers across our Domain. There is Windows 2008R2, Windows 2012, Windows 2016, and Windows 10. When I open a CMD and type

```
wmic /NODE:"Hostname" /USER:"Domain\AdminAcoount" OS GET numberofcores
```

I get

> Node - Hostname
>   ERROR:
>   Description = Invalid query

Any ideas what I am doing wrong?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The number of cores is part of the CPU, not the OS.

```
C:\>wmic /NODE:localhost cpu get NumberOfCores, NumberOfLogicalProcessors
NumberOfCores  NumberOfLogicalProcessors
4              8
```

When you are ready to step up to PowerShell.

```
PS C:\> Get-WmiObject Win32_Processor | Select-Object -Property NumberOfCores

NumberOfCores
-------------
            4
```

Or, from withing a cmd .bat script.

```
C:\>powershell -NoProfile -Command "& { Get-WmiObject Win32_Processor | Select-Object -Property NumberOfCores }"

NumberOfCores
-------------
            4
```

Comment: Thank you so much!! This absolutely did the trick: 

wmic /NODE:hostname cpu get NumberOfCores

Didn't even need the admin account